# PHPMYADMIN Blank Page

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I install vesta control panel on my ubuntu EC2 instance on AWS. By default vesta uses php 7.3 but my script demands php 5.6. So i had to downgrade my php version from and followed below method:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5.6
php -v

--This may show your old version.
--So now to switching the versions 7.0 > 5.6
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
--Basically need to install few modules first
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6
--enabling your required extensions example >>> sudo phpenmod mbstring
sudo apt-get update
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=6898

After PHP 5.6 is running fine but my phpmyadmin is showing blank page. I tried many online solutions but i couldn't resolve it.

Comment: Have you checked the error log for your Apache or php-fpm service?